# How to create a column with the sum of list values in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm quite new on pyspark and I'm dealing with a complex dataframe. I'm stuck trying to get **N** rows from a **list into my df.column** after some filtering.

I have the following df.struct:

```
root
 |-- struct1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- array1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- struct2 : struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- struct3 : struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- property: string (nullable = true)
```

What I want to achieve is get the **sum of all struct2.values** when the property is Good. Because I can have multiple(N) values for array1.

Right now, I got the a small sentence to get the first property. But I cant pass it to an udf in a success way to iterate over all possible rows:
`df.withColumn("Sum", (col('struct1.array1')[0])['property'])`

Some steps that I have in mind is:

- Filter each element inside the list when property=Good
- Return a lambda value in a udf with the sum of struct3.value

Desired output should be something like:

```
None
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Struct1                                                                                            |Sum|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[[[2020-01-01, 10], [2020-02-02, 15], Good], [[2020-01-01, 20], [2020-02-02, 25], Good]]]         |20|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any help will be appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need an UDF in this case. When using Spark >= 2.4.0 you can achieve the same just by using the build-in [high-order](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/apache-spark-2.4.0-features-array-higher-order-functions/read) functions as shown next:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr  

df.withColumn("good_elements", expr("""transform( \
                                         filter(struct1.array1, e -> e.property == 'Good'), 
                                         e -> cast(e.struct2.value as int)
                                    )""")) \
  .withColumn("sum", expr("aggregate(good_elements, 0, (sum, e) -> sum + e)"))
```

- `filter(struct1.array1, e -> e.property == 'Good')`: First we filter the items that have `property == 'Good'`
- `transform(..., e -> cast(e.struct2.value as int)`: Next we convert every item to an integer and store them into a new column called `good_elements`
- `aggregate(good_elements, 0, (sum, e) -> sum + e)`: finally we create the column `sum` by calculating the sum of `good_elements`

Comment: That is a pretty solution. I never heard about transform before. One question, It throws me an error: pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`struct2.value `' given input columns: [struct1];; I've tried to add the path since the beginning but still doesn't work. Do I need someting more to do to try your solution?

Comment: Yes there was a mistake @Als it should be `e.struct2.value` not `struct2.value`. e is the iterator that will go through the items of `filter(struct1.array1, e -> e.property == 'Good')`. I just changed it

Comment: I was debugging the function and I realize that the iterator e has the value. Thank you for the correction. It was really helpful @Alexandros Biratsis.

Comment: I am glad I could help @Als